# Ajax getting 500 internal error

Tags: php, ajax

So, I have a ajax setup with two contents from two separate files as shown below.

**Files:**

**my_site_id_one.php:**

```
<div class="id_one_content">
     <?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_one]'); ?>
</div>
```

**my_site_id_two.php:**

```
<div class="id_two_content">
     <?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_two]'); ?>
</div>
```

**Problem**

So, the ajax function itself works fine. For example, when I call for the "my_site_id_two.php", then it calls the `"[shortcode_two]"` and works just fine (meaning, it shows the `[shortcode_two]`content.

However with the `[shortcode_one]`, I am getting an error as following (from the console).

```
 Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<div class="royal_selection_heading   royal_heading_…rapper featured-item-list">
↵            
↵
↵    ", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}
```

Any advice to why it might be causing this? Or is it a more complicated problem than I think?

Thanks.

Comment: it seems to be problem with htaccess, for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is entirely a server side issue, not possibly related to your AJAX request.

An error of `5xx` means the request was sent successfully by the client, received successfully by the server, but while performing the associated work on the server something bad happened that triggered a fatal error, resulting in the termination of the PHP script.

[5xx Server Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error)

Comment: I see. Thank you for the information. It helped me to narrow down on the problem. Cheers!

Comment: thank you, minor bug in code wasted lot of my time, but it worked in localhost ..wonder

Comment: Hey guys! sorry for bringing this out from the grave, but I encountered a 500 internal error, and it doesnt seem to be code related. the function itself is a bit "loaded" with several arrays of strings and objects. Is there a chance that the amount of data will be to big, so the server will return a 500 error? 
in my case it happens when you add a product to the cart, with a lot of options selected and added to the product. its kind of stress test to the system. btw after refreshing the page the process is completed successfully...